# 2 textboxes in 2 form with the same name

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 similar form-blocks on form:

```
        <form action="/2/All/Home/SubIdeaComment?SubIdeaID=5576&amp;referrerUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A1261%2F2%2FAll%2FHome%2FIdea%2F5575%3FreferrerUrl%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A1261%252F2" method="post">



        <textarea id="SubComment" name="SubComment" style="width: 80%"></textarea>

        <br />

        <input type="submit" class="InputBtn" value="Reply" />

        <input type="reset" class="InputBtn" onclick="ShowHideReply($('#divSubIdeaReply5576'), $('#subIdeaButtons5576'))"

            value="Cancel" />

        <br />

        <br />

        </form>
```

and

```
        <form action="/2/All/Home/SubIdeaComment?SubIdeaID=5577&amp;referrerUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A1261%2F2%2FAll%2FHome%2FIdea%2F5575%3FreferrerUrl%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A1261%252F2" method="post">



        <textarea id="SubComment" name="SubComment" style="width: 80%"></textarea>

        <br />

        <input type="submit" class="InputBtn" value="Reply" />

        <input type="reset" class="InputBtn" onclick="ShowHideReply($('#divSubIdeaReply5577'), $('#subIdeaButtons5577'))"

            value="Cancel" />

        <br />

        <br />

        </form>
```

I need to call the same method of controller (MVC project):

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult SubIdeaComment(int SubIdeaID, string SubComment, string referrerUrl)
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SubComment))
            _repository.AddComment(User.Identity.Name, SubIdeaID, null, SubComment);
        return Redirect(referrerUrl);
    }
```

but when first form submits - I have SubComment as empty. As I understand, reason is 2 fields have the same name. But there are in different forms.... How to do it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

As you already correctly assumed, the `id`-attribute must be unique. I don't know exactly how those forms are being generated in your app, but maybe using [templates](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html) can help you out.

Comment: just saw ASP.NET Template - it generate elements with the same id inside